# Powershell not capturing exception in try/catch?

Tags: c#, powershell, try-catch, acl, ntfs

I have a piece of code like:
`...

    32: try {

    33:  set-acl -aclObject $AC -path $o.fullname

    34: } catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] {

    ...`
During execution I get this:

```
    set-acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
    At C:\script.ps1:33 char:3
    +         set-acl -aclObject $AC -path $o.fullname
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (N:\some_path:String) [Set-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Running as system.
Any idea why it's not being captured?

Comment: A workaround is to check $? and use IF

Comment: Are you running this remotely via invoke-command, by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `ErrorAction` parameter to `Stop`:

```
set-acl -aclObject $AC -path $o.fullname -ErrorAction Stop
```